# if element not excisted on page, how to pass that item?

Tags: python, selenium, coordinates

I have a new issue in web scraping?
I work on these 2 pages and I want to extract their location info as a part of web scraping process
Some items have exact lat long info and I could export them
But some has just a circle that represent approximate position of item
I want to check if this info existed extract location but if not pass to next item
But whatever I used not worked
here is my code:

```
from cgitb import text
from tkinter import END
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})


translationTable = str.maketrans("ğĞıİöÖüÜşŞçÇ", "gGiIoOuUsScC")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\\Prohit\\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
#driver.maximize_window()

actions = ActionChains(driver) 

url1 = 'https://www.hepsiemlak.com/istanbul-kadikoy-fenerbahce-satilik/daire/124037-400'
url2 = 'https://www.hepsiemlak.com/istanbul-kadikoy-acibadem-satilik/daire/2525-15017'

driver.get(url1)
#driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='80%'")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'modal__close'))
    )
finally:
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'modal__close').click()




driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[1]/section[3]/div/div[1]/div/section[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a').click()
time.sleep(5)
#click on harita
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="fullScreenWrapper"]/div/div[1]/button[2]/span').click()
time.sleep(3)

#-----------------------------

location_link=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="mapBlock"]/div/div[1]/div/a').get_attribute("href")


print('location:',location_link.split('cbll=')[1].split('&cbp=11')[0])
time.sleep(5)
print('location link length',len(location_link))
```

the url1 has location info and i can access but url2 not and break the total process

this method does not work:

if(len(location_link>0)):

## assign some info

have anyone suggesstions?

Comment: if len(location_link) > 0:  or if len(location_link) is not None:

Answer (score 0):

the true solution is:

```
    Location_Availability = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="mapBlock"]/div/div[1]/div').find_elements_by_css_selector("*")
    #print('Location_Availability:',Location_Availability)
    #print(len(Location_Availability))


    if len(Location_Availability)>2:
        location=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="mapBlock"]/div/div[1]/div/a').get_attribute('href').split('cbll=')[1].split('&cbp=11')[0]
        print('location:',location)
    else:
        print('no location')
```